# Users input a location - how do I loop through database containing routes

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic

I have a mySql database containing routes specified by lat and lng for start position and end position, and date and time for start.

Then I have a webpage (Classic asp) where users can input a date and time and location using Google maps api.

When a user type in a location I would like to loop through the database to see if any routes are passing the users location in the given time and then presents the results so that he can choose his preferred route.

I have been looking at isLocationOnEdge but I cant figure out how to use it and how to get the value out so I can use it in my asp.

I have found this code,but as I said - don't know have to use it so it suits my problem:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886, -70.269),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

  var cascadiaFault = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(49.95, -128.1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(46.26, -126.3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.3, -125.4)
    ]
  });

  var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(43.0, -125.9, 10e-7);

  if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition,     cascadiaFault)) {
    alert("Relocate!");
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Can anybody help me? Or just give some hints I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition, cascadiaFault)` will return a Boolean value that you can test, so I would suspect that you simply want to generate an array of values in your JavaScript code, something like...

```vbs
<%
    Dim sql, c, joinLL, rs, conn
    sql = "SELECT lat, long, FROM myGeoTable WHERE condition = true "
    conn = Application("CONN_STRING")

    'Pass the string using RecordSet.GetString...
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    rs.Open sql, conn
    joinLL = "[new google.maps.LatLng(" & _
      rs.GetString(2, , ", ", "), new google.maps.LatLng(", "") & _
      "]"
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
%>
```

...and, perhaps, something like this to test your long/lat list...

```cs
    // joinLL is the variable from the VB Script...
    var pLongLat = <%= joinLL %>;
    var llPoint;

    foreach(llPoint in pLongLat) {
        if(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(llPoint, cascadiaFault)) { 
            //Do your processing
        }
    }
```

It may be worth your while looking at the ADO RecordSet methods [`GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676975(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx); they're amazingly useful and very fast.

Comment: Thank you - but I still dont get it.
First of all, I have to have at least 4 latLongs for every route (StartLat, StartLng, EndLat, EndLng). And there can be viapoints too (from a related table). How do I get all all that in an array without knowing if there are 0, 1 or more viapoints?

And can I create a new list with all the routeId that comes out true? Because that list I could write in a hidden field and use in my asp.

When I do:LL = rs.GetString(2, , ", ", "), new google.maps.LatLng(", "")

Comment: I get this result:
[55.566962, 10.094465), new google.maps.LatLng(, ), new google.maps.LatLng(, ), new google.maps.LatLng(, ), new google.maps.LatLng(56.120638, 10.146379), new google.maps.LatLng(55.566962, 10.094465), new google.maps.LatLng(]

Comment: You'll need to exclude everything from your data where there are no lats and longs (i.e. where they are null or invalid), that's most likely why you're getting the `new google.maps.LatLng(, )`. Did you put that JavaScript in the HTML page at the end of my post? You'll have to put it between some `<script>` tags and perform your processing using this (i.e. whatever you wish to do).